# DAX Formula (Using Join)

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I'm looking to create a dax calculated column that uses two related tables. one is a dimension one is a fact. in MDX it looks like this:

```
Sum( 
   {[Tbl Master Measure Mapping].[Str Busies].[True]}
  ,[Measures].[Int Calls Offered]
)
```

in t-sql it looks like this:

```
select int_CallsOffered from fact_CallType_OTS a
inner join tbl_MasterMeasureMapping b on a.entName = b.entName
where b.Str_Busies = 'True'
```

Pretty Straight forward. This works in a cube no problem. How can i translate the above to a dax formula in power pivot ? would this be a measure or a calculated column ? i'm thinking calcualted column. I've looked on the internet, and a term "Evaluate" comes up, but i don't find that function in my version of power pivot. maybe i'm behind ? but i'd love to find a solution where i join just two tables (which i've defined the relationship on) and get a value back based on the where clause. Thanks.

b

Comment: can you share the table structure? which one is lookup? any real data examples?

Comment: hi, it's a very large table structure. The lookup table is tbl_MasterMeasureMapping. It contains true or false values. The referencing table is the fact table fact_CallType_OTS.

Answer (score 2):

You could create the measure using the [CALCULATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634825.aspx) function.

Call type OTS total:=CALCULATE(sum([Int Calls Offered]),'Tbl Master Measure Mapping'[Str Busies]=TRUE)

Note: your TSQL and MDX would not return the same thing as the TSQL is not aggregating

see https://msdn.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634825.aspx

Comment: is there a way to join that ? it's not returning anything, but i think it's because this condition isn't met: a.entName = b.entName ENT Name exists in both tables.

Comment: In analysis services\power pivot you would generally declare you relationships during the modeling phase so you do not need to declare them in your query like you would in T-SQL.  Unfortunately i don't really know how far you are in the modeling process so don't know exactly which step you need to complete to get the result you are looking for. but you can view one of the many tutorials such as this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231691.aspx that will guide you through the modeling phase.

Comment: I actually have defined the relationships in power pivot....its a very different world to me